# Can you set a fs to self-destruct

Tags: login

So i was wondering , if there is any measure to get in case your laptop gets stolen to make sure your data don't fall to the wrong hands . First idea that came up is to have an asymmetric encryption cast on all your files with you keeping the keys to another device or even paper . But my second thought i had seemed more realistic , e.g. if a password is entered wrong for lets say 10 times then the system would corrupt the data of /home . Is that possible in any degree ?

Comment: Sounds like something from "Mission Impossible". What happens when writing the script a bug treats it as stolen when it really isn't?

Comment: Obviously it would set the corruption sequence . But since you can write the corruption formula , in case the storm starts raging , you can cure it . Or so I had in my mind .

Comment: If ordinary encryption isn't protection enough, then you're talking about the [unrealistic](https://xkcd.com/538/) realm of movie-bad-guys-kidnapping-and-drugging you for the proper key to your [macguffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware that such a solution exists. The closest I see is using the pam module [faillock](https://www.tecmint.com/lock-user-accounts-after-failed-login-attempts-in-linux/), which locks a user account after a a number of failed login attempts. I guess one could write a pam module that does what you specify.

But this solution would not be secure at all. Lets assume I am an evil secret agent, I want access to some of your super secret data and I have managed to steal your laptop. In that case I would simply take out your hard drive plug it into an other computer and access it from there. Or I would boot your laptop from a flash drive.

---

Ubuntu offers an easy way to encrypt your home directory, which means unless you are logged in, I - as an attacker - can not access your data. This provides more security AND can not by accident destroy all your data

---

What could still be useful is a program that destroys data, when you want it. E.g. you know an evil secret agent will steal your laptop soon. and you are afraid they might be able to brake your encryption. But I think then `shred ~` would do the job

Comment: Thanks , guess im going a little bit overboard with this, but hey , always watch behind your back :)